# How to setup a Vagrant box for a stasis project?

Tags: ruby, puppet, vagrant

I'm learning how to use vagrant, and I've a simple project that uses [stasis](http://stasis.me/) to generate static files.

I'm looking for a setup to run stasis on a vagrant box.
So the question would be: **what's box do I need to make stasis work?**

(Any hints on what should the Puppetfile include would be nice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a posible solution I've used [this](https://gist.github.com/am/5442663) setup. It's a **[Ubuntu precise 64](http://files.vagrantup.com/precise64.box)** using puppet as provisioner with:

- rvm
- ruby 2.0.0
- git
- nodejs
- stasis gem
- project specific gems

I can compile the project and see it on `http://localhost:4000` using `stasis -d 4000`.

There is another [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167242/how-to-install-a-gem-into-rvm-with-puppet-on-a-vagrant-box) that came along when finding this solution.