# How to install a gem into rvm with puppet on a vagrant box?

Tags: rvm, puppet, vagrant

I've setup a simple Vagrant box with puppet provisioner. 
With puppet I've installed rvm:

```
exec { 'install_rvm':
  command => "${as_vagrant} 'curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable'",
  creates => "${home}/.rvm",
  require => Package['curl']
}
```

and ruby:

```
exec { 'install_ruby':
  command => "${as_vagrant} '${home}/.rvm/bin/rvm install 2.0.0 --latest-binary --autolibs=enabled && rvm --fuzzy alias create default 2.0.0'",
  creates => "${home}/.rvm/bin/ruby",
  require => Exec['install_rvm']
}
```

I'm trying to install a gem that would be available on the default ruby version of rvm (in this case 2.0.0)

If I try the puppet documented code it doen's work (I suppose it instals the gem on the system ruby):

```
package { 'sinatra':
    ensure   => 'installed',
    provider => 'gem',
}
```

**Current workaround:**  If I execute a command as a vagrant user it works, but it doesn't look nice:

```
$as_vagrant   = 'sudo -u vagrant -H bash -l -c'

exec { "${as_vagrant} 'sudo -u vagrant -H bash -l -c gem install stasis'":
  require => Exec['install_ruby']
}
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [this rvm module](https://forge.puppetlabs.com/maestrodev/rvm) from puppet forge. Check the [Vagrant documentation about puppet](http://docs-v1.vagrantup.com/v1/docs/provisioners/puppet.html) to know how to use puppet modules with vagrant.

Comment: Hi @Marcos Brigante, I had [something similar](https://github.com/blt04/puppet-rvm) in mind to try, but still would like to know how to do it using puppet out of the box.

Comment: Actually if you look at the module's code I think you'll find out how to do it with pure puppet. =]